# some diffence between spring webclient and httpsurlconnection to request a https interface

Tags: java, spring, https, webclient

request a https interface

first i use spring5 webclinet but it can't work

then i use httpsUrlConnection it work 
can you tell me difference between these code?

webclient:

```
WebClient.builder()
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(
                    HttpClient.create()
                            .secure(t -> t.sslContext(SslContextBuilder.forClient()
                                    .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)))))
            .build()
            .post()
            .uri("??????????")
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(i -> i.is4xxClientError(), res -> Mono.error(() -> new Exception("400")))
            .onStatus(i -> i.is5xxServerError(), res -> Mono.error(() -> new Exception("500")))
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .doOnSuccess(i -> System.out.println(i))
            .block();
```

httpsurlconnection

```
SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
sslcontext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{new TrustAnyTrustManager()}, new java.security.SecureRandom());
HttpsURLConnection conn =(HttpsURLConnection )   new URL("???").openConnection();
conn.setSSLSocketFactory(sslcontext.getSocketFactory());
conn.setHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier());
.........
```

i'm sure the url is a https interface, what's the different with these?